# Flutter - The screen is not scrolling

Tags: dart, flutter

I inserted 6 cards, however it is not possible to scroll the screen.

According to the image below, a red stripe appears in the footer, and the screen does not scroll.

What is missing to be able to scroll the screen?

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: "Myapp",
      home: new HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      backgroundColor: new Color(0xFF26C6DA),
    ),
    body: new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Card(
          child: new Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              const ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.album),
                title: const Text('The Enchanted Nightingale'),
                subtitle: const Text('Music by Julie Gable. Lyrics by Sidney Stein.'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        ...
        ...
        ...
      ],
    )    
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Columns don't scroll. Try replacing your outer Column with a ListView. You may need to put `shrinkWrap: true` on it.

Comment: I want to point out an answer below by Robert Felker. 
"A column in a column make the layout impossible to calculate without setting height..."
This answer is a little misleading, because a single column can scroll. Or a nested column with an expanded widget can as well.

Answer (score 27):

This might do the trick, worked like charm for me:

`shrinkWrap: true,  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),`

Comment: I had the shrinkWrap in true but I was missing the `physics: ClampingScrollPhysics()`, it works.  thanks

Comment: same with me  `physics: ClampingScrollPhysics()` is missing

Answer (score 26):

To make a column scrollable, simply wrap it in a [SingleChildScrollView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html).

Comment: At least in my case SingleChildScrollView does not work for Column. I had to use ListView.

Comment: In my case , In addition to this,  `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` was there in scaffold, commented it. Otherwise scroll will not work.

Answer (score 12):

I needed placing `SingleChildScrollView` inside `Column`. The `SingleChildScrollView` also needed `Column` as a child, but the scroll wasn't working for me in that case. The solution was to wrap the `SingleChildScrollView` with `Expanded`. So here's how it looked:

```
      Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          MyFirstWidget(),
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  // Scrollable content.
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: To make SingleChildScrollView with Column to scroll, this is the best solution

Answer (score 6):

you have to put it on ListView.builder

```
ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
    final item = yourItemLists[index];
    new Card(
      child: new Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          const ListTile(
            leading: const Icon(Icons.album),
            title: const Text('The Enchanted Nightingale'),
            subtitle: const Text('Music by Julie Gable. Lyrics by Sidney Stein.'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
  itemCount: yourItemLists.length,
);
```

Comment: Just changing the Column to ListView caused an exception. Moving the ListView into Expanded did the job as Vinoth Kumar suggested in another question. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50688970/cant-add-a-listview-in-flutter

Answer (score 4):

A column in a column make the layout impossible to calculate without setting height. 
The second column is useless since it contains only one element, try to put the ListTile directly as the body of the Card.

Answer (score 3):

You should use ListView.builder in place of the inner column (as I suggested above that columns are not scrollable).
Set shrinkWrap: true, and physics: ClampingScrollPhysics() inside ListView.builder. Just using shrinkWrap: true didn't solve my problem. But setting physics to ClampingScrollPhysics() started to make it scroll.

Comment: Setting the physics to ClampingScrollPhysics() worked for me, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

There are generally two ways to make a screen scrollable. One is by using `Column`, and the other is by using `ListView`.

**Use Column** (wrapped in `SingleChildScrollView`):

```dart
SingleChildScrollView( // Don't forget this. 
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Text('First'),
      //... other children
      Text('Last'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

---

**Use `ListView`:**

```dart
ListView(
  children: [
    Text('First'),
    //... other children
    Text('Last'),
  ],
)
```

This approach is simpler to use, but you lose features like `crossAxisAlignment`. For this case, you can wrap your children widget inside `Align` and set `alignment` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can also Wrap the parent Column in a Container and then wrap the Container with the SingleChildscrollView widget. (This solved my issue).

Answer (score 0):

Just Add  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),

Comment: That's the same as the other answer from this question; there's little value in repeating other answers on the question.

Answer (score 0):

set `scrollBehavior` in `MaterialApp` like :

```
scrollBehavior: const MaterialScrollBehavior().copyWith(
  dragDevices: {PointerDeviceKind.mouse,PointerDeviceKind.touch},
),
```

for example my app :

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GlobalProvider(
      child: MaterialApp.router(
...
        scrollBehavior: const MaterialScrollBehavior().copyWith(
          dragDevices: {PointerDeviceKind.mouse,PointerDeviceKind.touch},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```